# how should i use chainlink keeper

Tags: blockchain, solidity, chainlink

I'm learning free code camp solidity-js,（https://github.com/PatrickAlphaC/hardhat-smartcontract-lottery-fcc） following the video I wrote the code

I have deployed the raffle contract, and set up chainlink keeper, chainlink vrf, but when I run raffle.staging.test.js, my address sends eth to the contract address, but checkupkeep doesn't work, what could be causing this error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OtHJR.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tAZdg.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/smH0r.png)

Answer (score 0):

Two things to check:

1. Your accounts have balances.
2. Your timeout is set correctly. (https://hardhat.org/config/#json-rpc-based-networks)

example:

```
rinkeby: {
  url: RINKEBY_RPC_URL,
  accounts: PRIVATE_KEY !== undefined ? [PRIVATE_KEY] : [],
            //   accounts: {
            //     mnemonic: MNEMONIC,
            //   },
  saveDeployments: true,
  chainId: 4,
  timeout: 60000
}
```